# Armazenar dois nomes na mesma coluna

Tags: mysql, sql

Estou em dúvidas com relação a melhor prática para criar uma determinada tabela.

Eu tenho a tabela "Textos":

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu problema está com a coluna "autoria". Pois a autoria tem 3 opções veja:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se o usuário selecionar a segunda opção ele vai inserir o nome do co-autor. Nesse caso eu estava pensando em concatenar "autor em parceria com co-autor" E inserir dessa forma no banco de dados

Essa éuma boa maneira ? alguem tem alguma sugestão mais eficiente para resolver essa situação ?

Comment: Para seu banco de dados estar normalizado você deveria ter uma tabela a parte com os autores e uma tabela de ligação (representando um relacionamento N:N) fazendo a relação autor - texto.

Answer (score 1):

Essa ideia da concatenação não é algo muito bacana. 
O que eu posso sugerir para você é a criação de mais uma tabela, “Autores”, com os campos: id, nome_autor, nome_coautor ... . Dessa maneira, você pode setar uma relação dessa tabela com a tabela “Texto” e inserir os autores e co-autores nessa nova tabela.
Dessa maneira, você está respeitando os conceitos principais de um bom diagrama de banco de dados.